# Scaling in Meteor Cordova app on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

I have a webapp developed in Meteor using bootstrap 3 and when I build an iOS app and deploy it to an iPhone 6 it is "scaled" up. I have assets for 3x splash screen in mobile-config.js (see below) - what else could be causing it to scale? Thanks.

```
App.icons({
'iphone': 'resources/icons/iphone.png',
'iphone_2x': 'resources/icons/iphone_2x.png',
'iphone_3x': 'resources/icons/iphone_3x.png',
'ipad': 'resources/icons/ipad.png',
'ipad_2x': 'resources/icons/ipad_2x.png',
'android_ldpi': 'resources/icons/android_ldpi.png',
'android_mdpi': 'resources/icons/android_mdpi.png',
'android_hdpi': 'resources/icons/android_hdpi.png',
'android_xhdpi': 'resources/icons/android_xhdpi.png'
});

App.launchScreens({
'iphone': 'resources/splash/iphone.png',
'iphone_2x': 'resources/splash/iphone_2x.png',
'iphone5': 'resources/splash/iphone5.png',
'iphone6': 'resources/splash/iphone6.png',
'iphone6p_portrait': 'resources/splash/iphone6p_portrait.png',
'iphone6p_landscape': 'resources/splash/iphone6p_landscape.png',
'ipad_portrait': 'resources/splash/ipad_portrait.png',
'ipad_portrait_2x': 'resources/splash/ipad_portrait_2x.png',
'ipad_landscape': 'resources/splash/ipad_landscape.png',
'ipad_landscape_2x': 'resources/splash/ipad_landscape_2x.png',
'android_ldpi_portrait': 'resources/splash/android_ldpi_portrait.png',
'android_ldpi_landscape': 'resources/splash/android_ldpi_landscape.png',
'android_mdpi_portrait': 'resources/splash/android_mdpi_portrait.png',
'android_mdpi_landscape': 'resources/splash/android_mdpi_landscape.png',
'android_hdpi_portrait': 'resources/splash/android_hdpi_portrait.png',
'android_hdpi_landscape': 'resources/splash/android_hdpi_landscape.png',
'android_xhdpi_portrait': 'resources/splash/android_xhdpi_portrait.png',
'android_xhdpi_landscape': 'resources/splash/android_xhdpi_landscape.png'
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. In Xcode in the "General" tab for your app, go down to "app icons and launch images" and in Launch Screen File, set it to MainViewController